# MySQL: Interpolate monthly values from daily recordings

Tags: mysql, pdo, linear-interpolation

I would like to calculate monthly meter values from irregular readings. My data looks like this:

```
| Date       | Meter Reading   |
--------------------------------
| 2018-01-01 | 1.200           |  
| 2018-03-22 | 2.800           |  
| 2018-05-19 | 4.600           |
```

As you can see, the entries can happen any date and they are not on the first and / or last day of a month. For a monthly view I therefore need to interpolate the data and distribute it equally across the months between two readings.

If you interpolate the difference in the measurements and divide them with the days passed between them, you get two "daily" estimations of 30,19 and 31,03. This again multiplied with the number of days in each month results in (current day is assumed to be the 2018-05-19):

```
| Month      | Production |
---------------------------
| 2018-01    | 935,89     |  
| 2018-02    | 845,32     |  
| 2018-03    | 943,45     | 
| 2018-04    | 930,90     | 
| 2018-05    | 589,57     |
```

Is there a way to perform this on-the-fly query using SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: what exactly is your expected output? it looks different from input.

Comment: @Caius Jard: MySQL version currently used: 5.6.19. Salman: Yes, the second table is the wanted output calculating the production for each month.

Comment: @AntonSack Salman is essentially pointing out that there is no obvious way to turn 1.2 into 600. How does a daily total of 1.2 become a sum of 600 over 30 days? Even if I assume that the 1.2 grew linearly by ~0.016 per day to be 2.8 over 2.75 months, it's still not enough

Comment: Hi there, I edited the question accordingly. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Hi, the "." in 1.200 is a thousand separator!